# How do i get R data.tree print to show a value for each level?

Tags: r

I have a data frame, `struct`, showing a hierarchy of things:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
   lev1  lev2  lev3
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     A    AA   AAA
2     B    AA   AAA
3     C    BB   BBB
4     D    BB   BBB
```

In another data frame, `things`, a descriptor, `$Code`, for each thing:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 2
  Thing    Code
  <chr>   <chr>
1     A   11-11
2     B   22-22
3     C   33-33
4     D   44-44
5    AA 111-111
6    BB 222-222
7   AAA    <NA>
8   BBB    <NA>
```

I convert `struct` to a `data.tree` node:

```
struct$pathString <- paste("things",
                       struct$lev3,
                       struct$lev2,
                       struct$lev1,
                       sep = "/")

pfo <- as.Node(struct)
```

The `print(pfo)` command gives the output:

```
1 things       
2  ¦--AAA      
3  ¦   °--AA   
4  ¦       ¦--A
5  ¦       °--B
6  °--BBB      
7      °--BB   
8          ¦--C
9          °--D
```

What i want to see for each level is the appropriate value from `things$Code` after each `Thing` in the printed tree, like this:

```
1 things             Code
2  ¦--AAA         
3  ¦   °--AA      111-111
4  ¦       ¦--A     11-11
5  ¦       °--B     22-22
6  °--BBB      
7      °--BB      222-222
8          ¦--C     33-33
9          °--D     44-44
```

How can i assign these values and print them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that sorts both `Things` and the traversal on the tree alphabetically to match the codes:

```
#get the nodes corresponding to the struct elements as a traversal
trav <- Traverse(pfo, filterFun = isNotRoot)
#order alphabetically
trav <- trav[order(Get(trav, "name"))]

#also order things alphabetically
codes <- things[order(things$Thing), 2]

#assign codes to nodes
Set(trav, Code = codes$Code)

#print codes
print(pfo, "Code")
```

This will then print as desired:

```
      levelName    Code
1 things               
2  ¦--AAA              
3  ¦   °--AA    111-111
4  ¦       ¦--A   11-11
5  ¦       °--B   22-22
6  °--BBB              
7      °--BB    222-222
8          ¦--C   33-33
9          °--D   44-44
```